# Backend login page can't display correclty

Tags: magento-1, css, backend, admin-panel

After transferring to a new server, the backend login page can't load correctly, but the frontend works well. You can see the links of CSS and JS files are not correct. And the login button can't load either.

I have tried some ways:

1. set the right permission to the folders: skin, js.
2. clean the var folder.
3. set the right timezone in the table core_config_data
4. load the page with many browsers.

but unluckily they all failed.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check the base secure and unsecure url correctly from phpmyadmin

Comment: I used SSL for my site. The both urls are "htt  ps://ww  w.domain.com".

Comment: it's solved by this way: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-solution-to-error-404-not-found-in-admin-login-page/